# Avoid too long active transaction with IBX components

Tags: delphi, firebird

My question is very simple, what is the best practice to avoid to have too long active transaction with an application that use many component TIBDataSet? I would avoid to have very old OAT and than have very bad performance

My application have more dataset that must be always opened (until the application is running). I would avoid to close and reopen the transaction because I will be reopen all dataset.

I must be replace this component?
And if yes, what is the best choice?
ClientDataSet with DataSetProvider or switch to IBO component (also If I wouldn't install other component on my IDE)

Comment: `My application have more dataset that must be always opened ` 1) how would you detect if the content of the table on server changed while your app is running? 2) you can use any in-memory dataset for caching data, for example Delphi Pro comes with MIDAS/DataSnap library which has `TClientDataSet`, there are 3rd party ones too.

Comment: "because I will be reopen all dataset." - that sounds like you read THE WHOLE table into your application memory. That is poor approach for SQL, unless it is totally unavoidable to do. In general you only read exactly those columns and rows that your current task at hands (opened form, called procedure, etc) need and not a single row or column more than that.

Comment: @Arioch'The I have a global transaction for config and system data or data that doesn't change (or don't change very often, and changes coud be "catched" restarting the application). Caching data with TClientDataSet could be the better solution and I wanted to know if that's right; because so I must do many changes

Comment: Why not just closing that r/o transaction like once an hour, and when someone would re-fetch those configs or globals - let the transaction be auto opened ?

Comment: @Arioch'The yes, could be another solution, I would avoid possible error, AV or unpredictable behavior due to close and reopen dataset in unpredictable state...

Comment: AV should only be generated if the components are destroyed, but in my experience (not with IBX, but I guess this is common for all TDataSet-derived) even fields objects are persisted across close/open. The rest... I don't know. Frankly, it (a general design approach) is a balance between quickly accessing any setting (latency) and having always the latest values (coherence). If those config values are fetched like once a minute - then i'd fetch them from DB every time and not bother. If they are read many times a second, then caching is better.

Comment: And personally when I make quick hack-and-run fb projects I use UIB rather than ibx/fib+/ibo - just a personal preference :-D

Comment: The same solution given to your other question should be good here too: [TUIBEvents + other business logic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57832734/2110862)

Answer (score 1):

Read-only transactions don't affect performance of FB server. In our project we use single projectwide read-only always open transaction for data fetching and multiple short living transactions for data modification.

We use modified IBX components where second separate transaction for data reading was added.

Comment: Ok, now for general dataset I use read-committed transaction, that type are more lightweight then snapshots transaction; but readonly are so more better?

Comment: internally read-only read_committed transactions start in "committed" mode (not in "active"). This means they don't hold record versions nor prevent garbage collection. In case when Firebird serves hundreds of simultaneous connections it provides some performance gains.

Comment: `Read-only transactions don't affect performance of FB server` - no, it still may have BLOB handles leak, especially in FB 2.1 where functions like LIST could not use VARCHAR datatype. So even those long transactions are better to be closed at least once an hour

Comment: @MarcoAndreolli like I said, long reader plus many short writers was a popular model for Interbase and Firebird, just it has this gotcha hard to detect when developing (you would not truly actively use your program for many consequent hours during debug session). So it takes either a persistent caution not to fall into any BLOB-related operations, or a timer to commit and reopen the transaction once in a while. In general this is a viable approach.